# Set-cookie in response not set for Angular2 post request

Tags: angular, cookies

When I make a put request in Angular2, I receive the expected set-cookie in the response. However my browser (tried both Chrome and Firefox) refuses to set the cookie.

Instead when I use an Angular 1 app making a call to the *same* API endpoint, the cookies are set correctly.

The response headers are:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com
Allow:GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 28 Jan 2016 14:41:38 GMT
P3P:policyref="http://www.example.com/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP COR CURa TIA"
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
Set-Cookie:sessionid=994wl49qfsizog5bqmt57sgx9q2toa25; expires=Mon, 28-Mar-2016 14:41:37 GMT; Max-Age=5183999; Path=/
Set-Cookie:csrf=u7UQhpAphTsGYKRU6jFlLFt6NoYAhNMS; Domain=api.example.com; expires=Thu, 26-Jan-2017 14:41:38 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary:Accept, Cookie
```

The backend is programmed in Django 1.8.

Does anyone experienced the same thing or have a suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I seems to be a CORS-related issue. Perhaps you could try to set the `withCredentials` attribute when executing the HTTP request.

This answer could help you to find out how to do that, especially the [Cedric Exbrayat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971121/cexbrayat)'s answer:

- [angular2 xhrfields withcredentials true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007572/angular2-xhrfields-withcredentials-true/)

**Edit**

You could extend the `BrowserXhr`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

If you need more hints about CORS, you could have a look at this link: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks! But for me it is not very clear where I have to put Cedric's code :)

Comment: I think the Cédric's code should put before the call of the `bootstrap` function. I also provides you another way that should work but I didn't test it...

Comment: I've ended up by putting it in the constructor of my api service. Thanks! :)

Comment: @osi Could I see an example of how you did this?

Answer (score 20):

Indeed a CORS issue.
From Angular2 RC2 on, you just need to

```
this.http.get('http://my.domain.com/request', { withCredentials: true })
```

Comment: coresponding angular 2 docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html

Comment: Note for anyone like me who read that too quickly here and everywhere else it's advised - that's just a setting that Angular uses, and is given as an attribute of the same object you use to pass in headers. *It's not a header itself.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but for me the cookie had a path to '/api/order'.. So only request to this path contained the cookie.. I altered the path to '/' and now everthig is fine..