# Set-cookie headers missing in Angular 4 XHR response

Tags: angular, header, setcookie

I am firing an XHR request from Angular 4 to a token endpoint at `/oauth/token` and I don't see the `set-cookie` headers that I am expecting when debugging the response.

In do see them in curl, Chrome's network tab, Firefox's network tab and Postman, just not in Angular 4.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064648/set-cookie-in-response-not-set-for-angular2-post-request) and included the 'withCredentials' property to no avail.

Screenshot of Chrome's Network tab:

[image]

Screenshot of Chrome debugger below. There are no set-cookie headers in the _headers array and trying to specifically grab them (`let setCookieHeader = res.headers.get('set-cookie')`) results in `null`.

[image]

Any ideas why the `set-cookie` headers are missing?

Comment: Did you get to solve it ?

Comment: No. I moved Angular 5 and used this package to get cookies in Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service