# Making an API call from browser works, but not from front end app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

I have two separate projects: a front end app (Angular 2, using Visual Studio Code) and a back end app (ASP.NET Core, using Visual Studio 2015). For the back end app, when I did File > New Project, I selected "Windows Authentication."

Under Properties, I have these boxes checked:

[image]

When I make a call to this API from my **browser**, it works just fine:

[image]

```
        // GET: api/card
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = ActiveDirectory.User)]
        public Card[] Get()
        {
            var cards = _cardData.GetAll().ToList();

            var result = cards
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastChanged);

            return result.ToArray();
        }
```

But when I make a call from the **front end app**, I get a 401 error:

[image]

```
    private _cardUrl = 'http://localhost:8462/api/card';

    getCards(): Observable<Card[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._cardUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <Card[]>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I should point out that when I remove this line, it works just fine: `[Authorize(Roles = ActiveDirectory.User)]`

I am definitely a member of this role, it just isn't recognizing it when I make the call from the front end app like it does when I make the call from my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to front end app:
https://github.com/angular/http/issues/65#issuecomment-181560171

Add this to back end app in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your projects deployed to different domains? (`http://localhost:8462` and `http://localhost` are considered different domains)

If yes, you have to add `withCredentials: true` to your Angular2 HTTP backend.

See also: [angular2 xhrfields withcredentials true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007572/angular2-xhrfields-withcredentials-true)

Comment: Yes, the back end app is on http://localhost:8462 and the front end app is on http://localhost:3000.

Comment: Then you must add `withCredentials` otherwise browsers will not send any credential information over XHR.