# Http post,with credentials.What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: http, angular, xmlhttprequest

1.I can't setup a proper request, with useCredentials.Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable ()
export class StructureRequestService {
result: Object;
constructor (private http: Http) {
```

2.use XHR object - I think the problem is here.

```
    let _build = (<any> http)._backend._browserXHR.build;
    (<any> http)._backend._browserXHR.build = () => {
        let _xhr =  _build();
        _xhr.withCredentials = true;
        return _xhr;
    };
}
private myUrl = 'http://manny.herokuapp.com/audit/get/structure';

//create an http request
sendRequest() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
       // , withCredentials: true
    });
    return this.http.post(this.myUrl,options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {this.result = res;});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the post body parameter in your post request. It must be a string

```
 return this.http.post(this.myUrl, body, options)
```

> Body
>
> Despite the content type being specified as JSON, the POST body must actually be a string. Hence, we explicitly encode the JSON hero content before passing it in as the body argument.

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: oh. thanks.What if I don't have body param to send?  
 And how about  withCredentials: true part ? is it done correct?

Comment: @Serhiy check this post about that subject http://stackoverflow.com/q/35007572/5706293

Comment: cool. your advice works. I just missed body, I used that in Angular 1 I sent this request without body, just like this. And I could'n find what is a problem. You helped me a lot. thank you!!!

Comment: i tried this but still getting a 401 on put. gets are going through no problem